# Unchecked event for checkbox on datagrid not firing

Tags: c#, wpf

I have events handled for checked/unchecked for checkboxes on a datagrid

```
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Emp Acknowlegement" Binding="{Binding Path=Trained}" Width="*">
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    <EventSetter Event="Checked" Handler="empAck_OnCheck"/>
                    <EventSetter Event="Unchecked" Handler="empAck_OnUncheck"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding isUser}" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Effectiveness Check" Binding="{Binding Path=EffectiveCheck}" Width="*">
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    <EventSetter Event="Checked" Handler="effAck_OnCheck"/>
                    <EventSetter Event="Unchecked" Handler="effAck_OnUncheck"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Level}" Value="2">
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

The checkbox fires both events. The first one only fires the Checked event. I swapped the handlers for Checked and Unchecked to see if it was the unchecked method causing the issue but it ran correctly. It appears the event isn't firing. The code for the second box is identical but and it fires as expected.

```
    private void empAck_OnCheck(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Checked");

    }

    public void empAck_OnUncheck(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unchecked");

    }
```

Comment: Use the Style for EditingElementStyle instead of ElementStyle. Or make it a resource and use it for both. Either way, using it for EditingElementStyle will fix the problem.

Comment: @EdPlunkett that did it, if you post it as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks so much.

Comment: Actually, now I can't reproduce the issue, so I'm not at all confident I know what happened. I think mine was failing at first because `isUser` was undefined in the row viewmodel I was using, not because of the style.

Comment: @EdPlunkett honestly I have no idea why your solution worked for this particular checkbox when the others I have don't require it. It works now though, I just have no idea why.

Comment: Yeah. We haven't answered the question.

Comment: What's also strange is when I use editingelementstyle instead of elementstyle the checkbox looks disabled but it's still checkable

Comment: With EditingElementStyle, there's an editing state, and a non-editing state. With only EditingElementStyle set, add this to the Style: `<Setter Property="Content" Value="EditingElementStyle" />`. When you're not editing the cell, the style isn't applied. When I just use EditingStyle, and add `<Setter Property="Content" Value="ElementStyle" />` to that style, I find that it always has ElementStyle for the content (i.e., in that case there's no editing-vs-non-editing state change). So now I'm wondering what your `isUser` property is returning, and when.

Comment: isUser is just a 1 or a 0, in this case it would be a 1. It's set when a user logs in.

Comment: I'd try to get a reproducible example together. I don't think it's being caused by anything visible in the code you posted.

Comment: I actually noticed my isdisabled issue is for every column, it only works if I set them to readonly elsewhere in the code. If they're set to read only, enabling and disabling works as expected. The original issue still persists, I just can't figure out why your solution works for that specific column yet is unnecessary for the others.

Comment: That's what the reproducible example is for. My copy of your XAML works fine for me without my "solution". If we knew all the differences between your code/XAML and mine, we could identify what's going on.

Comment: <EventSetter Event="Clicked" Handler="empAck_OnClicked"/>